# Timeout form waitFormessage

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a logic like below to read topic

ar_pose::ARMarkersConstPtr msg_mark = ros::topic::waitForMessage<ar_pose::ARMarkers>("ar_pose_marker");

Is there any way to time out waiting period if topic is not being published for a longer time?

abhy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9660/timeout-form-waitformessage/) by [abhy](https://answers.ros.org/users/388/abhy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can find this on the [API](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html), you can specify a time-out as follow:

```
 waitForMessage (const std::string &topic, ros::Duration timeout)
```

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2